# What regulations are there when naming boolean in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, passwords, boolean, verification

I have written a program which will determine if a password is strong(has 10+ letters, 1+ capital letters and numbers) and if not, it will ask for a stronger password. To do this, I have chosen to use boolean but IDLE says that there is incorrect syntax and highlights my boolean names. Is the issue with the name or is there something else that I should correct/

```
        def length(long):
    while len(long) < 10: 
        print("Please make your password longer, up to at least 10 characters.")
        print("Your password is only " + str(len(long)) + " characters long")

print("Welcome to this student interface")
username = input("Please enter a username")
password = input("Please enter a strong password")
length(password)

bool Capcheck = False
bool DigCheck  = False

serrors = []

while CapCheck = False or CapCheck = False:
    length(password)

    if not any(x.isupper() for x in password):
        serrors.append("Your password needs at least 1 capital.")
    else:
        CapCheck = True
        break

    if not any(x.islower() for x in password):
        serrors.append("......... Why?")

    if not any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
        serrors.append("You need to have at least 1 digit")
    else:
        DigCheck = True
        break

    if serrors:
        print(" ".join(serrors))
        password = input("Please enter a stronger password")
```

Comment: `while CapCheck = False or CapCheck = False:` is a syntax error.  You need `==`, not `=`.

Comment: `bool Capcheck = False` what is this supposed to be doing? It's not valid python

Comment: Also, your variable is actually named `Capcheck`, not `CapCheck`.

Comment: Also also, why are you checking the exact same condition `CapCheck = False` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
bool Capcheck = False
```

should be replaced with

```
Capcheck: bool = False
```

see [Python type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: Note that type hints in Python are optional. In a language like Java or C you need to specify the type of your variables, but in Python you do not. So you could just use `Capcheck = False`

Comment: While Python continues to be a dynamically typed language, the typing module is a standard module for a good reason: "Explicit is better than implicit" (see "The Zen of Python"). Hence I don't see why this question has been heavily downvoted.